# libcurl IMAP not working

Tags: c++, c, email, imap, libcurl

Using the below code, I'm trying to get *any* of the libcurl IMAP commands to work.

Currently, regardless of the command set via CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, in my callback function the only data that is given is the oldest email (1st) in my inbox. I can even put something like "dfsafdasfasfaf" in the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, and no error will be shown, and the oldest email will be printed from the callback.

I've tried using the sample codes on libcurl's site, to list folders, LSUB, etc and it's always the same - the only thing returned is the contents of the 1st email in my inbox.

I'm using curl 7.40 mingw32 on win32 g++ (-lcurldll).

Surely I must be doing something wrong. If you could take a moment to correct my error, I would be most appreciative. Thank you.

EDIT - Even if you don't know the answer, could you please leave a comment if you have successfully gotten libcurl IMAP to work before? Because if no one has gotten libcurl imap to work before I'll stop wasting my time with it and move on to VMime or another option..

EDIT2- My principal question is how can I list folders via libcurl?

```
size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{   
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
} 


int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "gmailuser");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "password");


        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "LIST");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);


        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",  curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   }

  _getch (); 
  return (int)res;

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your input REACHUS - I'd like to start by listing all of the folders for the gmail account.

Comment: You can list all of the folders by simply using `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com/")`. Also, I believe you don't need `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "LIST")` but I understand you want to format the output in some way.

Comment: Thanks again for your followup comment. I have tried what you said, and like I said - in my callback function where I print the 1st argument (buf) - it contains nothing about INBOX folders and only the contents of the 1st message of the INBOX. Can you please tell me how exactly I'm supposed to read the INBOX folders? What buffers does the text get put into? I appreciate your time.

Comment: REACHUS - have you personally had success with that? I see on the curl mailing list there's many people w/IMAP problems, although it seems to work ok on command line. Can you tell me what version of cURL you got that to work for?

Comment: I am using `libcurl 7.35.0`. Also, in my case it doesn't print the first e-mail. I've also checked the mailing list and see that many people have problems with libcurl and its current IMAP supports.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually had a similar SMTP problem where SMTP worked w/an older version but not newer so this isn't surprising. I can't find a download link for 7.35 - could I trouble you to upload it to sendfile or another host and post the link? Since you can confirm it works -  if you mark that as an answer I'd gladly mark the question answered : )

Comment: Unfortunately I have just installed from an Ubuntu package but I will post an answer with ZIP file with source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get list of folders in a given GMail inbox, you should use:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com/");
```

Also, I believe [you don't need this line to perform LIST request](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/imap-list.html):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "LIST");
```

I have tested it on Linux, on libcurl version 7.35.0, though I believe the problems you are encountering are not OS-specific and are rather caused by the current state of the implementation of IMAP support in the library. You can find source code for libcurl version 7.35.0 [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.35.0.zip).

You can also find more examples of current libcurl IMAP support on the [examples page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) (see the links on the right for more detailed examples).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that - but do you know where I can download the development package? Filename should be something like curl-7.35.0-devel-mingw.

Comment: I would try either on of these: http://lrn.no-ip.info/packages/i686-w64-mingw/curl/7.35.0-1/ or try to cross-compile it (I saw some mails on the libcurl mailing list on how to do this).

Comment: On Windows they issue "devel" packages w/libraries, .dll's, and include files. Given the current state of libcurl I think manually compiling sounds like a rather time wasting gamble I'm not willing to take so I will use their command line tool until I get VMime up and working, but thanks again for your help.